# Create Android preference in settings to set password

Tags: android, settings, preferences

I would like a setting in preferences that allows the user to create a password. The perfect example is in the Play Store. In settings you click on Password and a dialog box pops up with an `EditText` field with a password field that hides the characters. How would you do that?

I'm pretty sure this is not `EditTextPreference`. Is this a custom preference? How would you make this? Can I get a sample for the XML part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure this is not EditText preference

`EditTextPreference` would work. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html):

> This EditText can be modified either programmatically via getEditText(), or through XML by setting any EditText attributes on the EditTextPreference.

So adding `android:password="true"` as part of your preference XML should work.

That being said, you are certainly welcome to create your own custom `DialogPreference` for this.

Comment: Oh nice. Simpler than imagined. I looked for the password option in the XML preference, and Eclipse didn't show it as an option.  Didn't actually try though.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: Yeah, I don't think the preference editor is that sophisticated, particularly since (AFAIK) this is the only preference that exhibits this sort of "inherit attributes from a widget" behavior.

Comment: `android:password` is deprecated, use `android:inputType="textPassword"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using intents

In some cases, you might want a preference item to open a different activity instead of a settings screen, such as a web browser to view a web page. To invoke an Intent when the user selects a preference item

it's available at android guide, check this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Intents